# ER-Model: Model that child entities can be each other

Tags: inheritance, entity-relationship

I have a question about inheritance in ER-Modells:

Given over-simplified example of inheritance:

[image]

How can I show that students can be workers and vise versa?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In DB Design, there is no Inheritance concept. We achieve both IS-A(Inheritance) and HAS-A(Composition) through foreign keys.

Ex: Car has Engine
cars table refer engines table with a foreign key.

Ex: Student is a person
students table refer person table with a foregin key

Now, what you want to achieve is a Student should be a worker.

Its simple. Basically a Student is a Person. So that particular person can also 
be a worker.

[image]

[image]

A person can be both Student and Worker, which satisfies your requirements.

```
If both Student and Worker are referring a same foreign key person_id i.e
That implies the person is both a Student and Worker.
```